# Is it true that Hideyo Noguchi had neurosyphilis when carrying out his last experiments in Africa?

Tags: biographical-details, death, medicine

[On the Wikipedia page on Hideyo Noguchi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hideyo_Noguchi#Death), one can find the following:

> Possibly his erratic and irresponsible behaviour was caused by the
>   untreated syphilis with which he was diagnosed in 1913, and which may
>   have progressed to neurosyphilis. In any case, he was careless not
>   only of his own safety, but also of the safety of those around him,
>   and despite repeated promises to Young, failed to keep infected
>   mosquitoes in the specially designed secure housing.

Is there any study confirming or refuting that Hideyo Noguchi had neurosyphilis?

Comment: Perhaps this question is a little *too* specific, even for this site.

Comment: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%87%8E%E5%8F%A3%E8%8B%B1%E4%B8%96#.E5.8C.BB.E5.AD.A6.E8.80.85.E3.81.A8.E3.81.97.E3.81.A6

Answer (score 1):

In 1928, at may 11 he was diagnosed yellow fever. He felt strange because he had immunity of yellow fever. However after he died, and his blood was injected to a monkey. The monkey was diagnosed yellow fever. Then also Dr.young died with yellow fever after about one week.

Comment: Can you expand more on how this answers the question? I don't quite see how it confirms that Noguchi had neurosyphilis.

Comment: Furthermore, some sources would be nice.

Comment: Sources are japanese, so I didn't paste.